# Suggestion for trigger that sends email if threshold is broken

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

This is quite a broad question but ill try and summarise it as best I can.

I have an MVC front end which displays/allows processing of records which are classed as outstanding. I also have a scheduled console app which runs nightly and attempts to resolve each of these records using some logic I wrote.

I have a new requirement, which is to have an email sent every time the total number of outstanding records exceeds a certain amount, this amount needs to be configurable.

The table will contain every record with a flag to say if they have been resolved or not, so I will need to count the outstanding's then fire an email to notify if the threshold is broken.

I initially thought about adding a SQL Server trigger on insert however I soon realised that if no more records were added for a few days but the total number stayed above the threshold because nobody resolved them, then no further email would be sent.

I need the email to send every day on a schedule independently of insert/update.
So now I'm thinking possibly a SQL Server job, or an SSIS package or even a service which runs, but I'm aware this threshold number needs to be configurable.

So what would be the quickest simplest solution to my requirements, I'm open to any suggestion as long as it ticks all the boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the OP already has a console app running on a schedule, the most logical choice would be to simply add this check to the console app along with the email sending logic. It will be much easier to send emails that way, anyways, especially if you employ something like Postal, which will let you use MVC-style views to create your emails.

Answer (score 1):

An SQL Server scheduled job seems to me to be the simplest way to go.
you can add a table to your database that will hold the threshold number and read it's value from there.
In many cases a GeneralParams table is a good thing to have anyway.

The other option you mentioned (windows service) is also configurable in many ways: you can use a GeneralParams table, or the App.Config file of the service (but you will have to restart it every time you change the app.config), or even a simple text file. anything goes. the downside is that it's outside of your sql server, but the upside is that it is probably easier to send emails from.

Comment: I agree. Should have thought about it myself.